# Script to add same number daily plus one more number at the end of the month

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a script that adds 3+ daily starting from zero at the beginning of the year, and add +37 at the end of the month. Plus it has to also to take into account leap years. This is what I have so far...

```
// Calculate new members since Jan 1st 2016
var initialDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1); // Jan 1st 2016
var now = Date.now();
var difference = 3 * (now - initialDate);
var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay);

// Write result to HTML
document.getElementById('members_since').innerHTML = daysSince;
```

I'm very a Javascript and I have no idea how to take into account leap year and 37 at the end of each month. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show an example (snippet) that almost does what you want and then tell exactly what is expected. Can you for example explain WHAT you are looking for instead of describing how you THINK it can be solved? There is nothing in your question that shows a need for taking leap years into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many duplicates that calculate date differences, but perhaps you want something like this?

```
var aDay = 24*60*60*1000, 
      today = new Date(), 
      jan_first = new Date(today.getFullYear(),0,1,12,0,0,0).getTime();
today.setHours(12,0,0,0);
var endOfThisMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(),
      today.getMonth()+1,0,12,0,0),
      diff=today.getTime()-jan_first,
      total=Math.round(diff/aDay)*3;
total+=today.getMonth()*37;
if (today.getTime()==endOfThisMonth) total+=37;
```

Comment: The number represents a quantity of members being helped at a company, they gave a formula of basically +3 daily (starting from zero at the beginning of the year) and they add +37 at the end of the month. So far I feel like I got the +3 part but it's not taking into account that 2016 is a leap year.

Comment: Have a look at the not tested update. Your algorithm is a guesstimate so handling leap year is making the guesstimate a very precise one ;) but my code does handle it since it is using absolute days

Comment: Thank you!!! Will this algorithm restart at the beginning of the year by any chance?